# How to set APIKEY in PHP CURL call to IBM Natural Language Understanding

Tags: php, curl, ibm-watson

I am trying to set the APIKEY value in CURL for authentication to the IBM Natural Language Understanding API in a PHP application.

I have no problem using the ...CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$usname:$pword"... option in my CURL call, but I'm not sure how to use the new API apikey:"xxxxx" method.  There is only a apiKey provided now.

I've also tried placing the authorization apikey in my $header_args section like this:

```
$header_args = array(
   'Accept: application/json',
   'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   'Authorization: apikey:xxxxxxx
);
```

// Set options for REST call via curl

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $endpointurl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //set to 'true' so array returns to $result
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$usname:$pword"); <= this works fine
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'apikey:' . $apikey);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_args);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

I expect that i receive results in $results.  instead I receive 
{"code":401, "error": "Unauthorized"}

Comment: Your code seems correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: Have you double checked you are using the correct access token?

Comment: Use as you use `"$usname:$pword"` substituting `apikey` for `$usname`. If you still are getting an unauthorized error, then check the url endpoint that you are using. The endpoint differs depending on the region in which you created your instance of the Watson service. So if you have a `Frankfurt` apikey, it won't be valid against a `London` bound service.

Answer (score 0):

Even I too faced the same issue but with c code.
Firstly you check with the postman whether your endpoints are working, if it is working then there is a problem in your code.
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'apikey:' . $apikey);` -> did not work for me .
So I sent the API key in the header.
The header format you followed requires small correction it is :
use `x-api-key:"apiKey value"` instead of Authorization

```
$header_args = array(
   'Accept: application/json',
   'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   'x-api-key: apikey:xxxxxxx
);
```